# Razorpay Subscriptions vs Razorpay Orders

Tags: razorpay

So I have 2 different models - one is using subscriptions and the other is using orders.

Now I am using RazorPay Webhook can someone tell me how can I see the difference that this coming Webhook is for order or subscription?

I have opt Webhook for `order.paid` for orders and for subscription, I have opted for these - subscriptions.authenticated,subscription.activated,subscription.charged,subscription.completed,subscription.updated,subscription.pending,subscription.halted,subscription.cancelled,subscription.paused,subscription.resumed.

Now if I am going to take a subscription, instead of hitting subscription Webhook API orders Webhook is hitting i.e `order.paid` Webhook!

Please tell me how can I see or make the difference in payment transactions for subscriptions and orders?

I am using React JS on Web and Node JS at the backend.